# Establecer timeOut al presionar boton para evitar saturacion del servidor

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy haciendo un pequeño panel de administración, de forma que puedo ver los usuarios de la base de datos y eliminarlos y modificarlos.

Me he fijado en que cuando se hacen muchos clicks seguidos en el boton de modificar, como este hace peticiones a la base de datos, el servidor se satura y crashea.

No se si es mejor desde el servidor rechazar la solicitud, o evitar que el servidor se sature desde el cliente.

Este es mi formulariocodigo en AngularJS:

```
<div id="user-manage">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive  border border-1 mt-3">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Occupation</th>
          <th scope="col">Manage</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="row-{{user._id}}" class="text-center" *ngFor="let user of users">
          <td scope="col text-center">{{user.full_name}}</td>
          <td scope="col text-center">{{user.occupation}}</td>
          <td class="col text-center ">
            <button id="del-{{user._id}}" (click)="openDeleteUserModal(user._id)" class="border-0 "
              data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#del-user-modal"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
            <button id="mod-{{user._id}}" class="btn_delay" (click)="openModifyUserModal(user._id);" class="border-0"><i
                class="fas fa-pencil"></i></button>
            <button class="border-0"><i class="fas fa-gear"></i></button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>



  </div>
</div>
```

Se me ocurre establecer un timeOut desde el cliente al hacer click en un boton, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo. ¿Se os ocurre algo? Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: También puedes deshabilitar los botones mientras la petición no termine.

Comment: No se si estas directamente contra la base de datos o alguna api, pero lo mejor es que el propio backend no permita esto. en definitiva la opcion de @Suso me parece bien, o si no algun tipo de temporazador que desabilite el boton unos segundos..

Comment: @zabbix estoy con una api. Entonces lo mejor es que el backend te lo rechace verdad? El problema es que no se como controlar que cuando este atendiendo una petición, no pueda entrar ninguna más. He probado un try catch, pero no lo controla

Comment: @Angel Normalmente la propria api tiene que tener un limite de peticiones en un tiempo X, y la api rechaza la peticion tu haces el handling del status code que te da la api y listo (con esto quiero decir que dependiendo del status code de la llamada haces una cosa o otra.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu caso al conectarte a una API, lo recomendable es que el propio backend tenga un limite de peticiones por X tiempo, y tu hacer un handling del status code que te vaya dando la API o del json o xml que te de.

de ejemplo:

Si la api te da de status code 200 pues significa que la peticion se realizo con exito.

Pero si la api te da 429 pues significa que haces demasiadas peticiones y se lo enseñas por pantalla al usuario.

aqui tienes los status codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Asi te evitas problemas en un futuro (en temas de seguridad), digamos que un temporizador en frontend es facil de esquivar xd.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la idea! No quería hacerlo por frontend por eso mismo, porque cualquiera se lo puede saltar

Comment: De todas formas, esta solución no descarta que anules mientras el botón al pulsar, piensa que muchas veces el usuario hace doble-click, por costumbre. Así evitas sacar la advertencia de "demasiadas peticiones".